# How to get Paragraph Changed Time?

Tags: hooks

I know how get User entity changed time (`$user->getChangedTime()`).
Node has the same value (`$node->changed`), but I need to get this changed time from a `Paragraph`.

When I try this method `$paragraph->getChangedTime()` (the value `changed` do not exists) i got this:

*Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph::getChangedTime() ...*

I have this field in my *User* entity, and I need to know when this field is changed. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: The Paragraph entity doesn't have a changed field. You need your own date field and fill it in a presave hook.

Comment: Paragraphs (and all entity reference revision fields) are directly tied to their parent entity, AFAIK their revisioning is completely tied to the host too. If you save the host, a new revision of all paragraphs is created, so a changed timestamp doesn't really make sense here by architecture of the module. If you need a separate changed timestamp, Paragraphs is the wrong tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a date/time field to the paragraph type and fill in the current time if the paragraph is changed:

*mymodule.module*

```
<?php

use Drupal\paragraphs\ParagraphInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
use Drupal\datetime\Plugin\Field\FieldType\DateTimeItemInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave() for paragraph entities.
 */
function mymodule_paragraph_presave(ParagraphInterface $paragraph) {
  if ($paragraph->getType() == 'my_paragraph_type') {
    if ($paragraph->isChanged()) {
      $paragraph->field_date->value = (new DrupalDateTime('now', DateTimeItemInterface::STORAGE_TIMEZONE))
        ->format(DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did not knew something like `$paragraph->isChanged()` existed. Is this paragraphs specific or can this be used with other entities too?

Comment: This is specific to paragraphs but it's basically the same as if you would compare with $entity->original. So you could define a custom changed time for the content of a specific field or a set of fields in any entity.